# Switching between USB-Ethernet Device and WiFi

Tags: debian, networking, raspbian, dhcpcd

I am trying to setup the network configuration of Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Stretch so that I can use my AT&T LTE (WNC) kit (A USB-Ethernet Device) when it is physically connected and WiFi Network when not connected.
My /etc/network/interfaces file

```
auto wlan0
auto lo iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug eth1 
iface eth1 inet dhcp   
  post-up route add default eth1

allow-hotplug wlan0 iface wlan0 inet manual
  wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1 iface wlan1 inet manual   
  wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

The default route gets added to the eth1 even when it i not connected. How can i modify it or move it to dhcpcd.conf so that the default path is given to the eth1 when connected and wlan0 when not.

Comment: The problem is probably that from the ethernet point of view they are indeed always connected.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro can we add something like if /sys/class/net/eth1 exist then add default route to eth1 if it doesn't then add default route to wlan0? If yes then where?

Comment: You can probably do it with a script, seems a dirty solution. I am used to solve this situations in enterprise settings with dynamic routing, which is not appropriate here. I am not so used to the desktop, lets see if someone proposes a better idea.